# Combine rows by id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have the following types of data. How to combine rows by id, and the type record a separate column (all types 10) (or record types, separated by commas in a single column)

```
id,type,value
1,8,value1
1,2,value1
1,7,value1
1,3,value1
1,10,value1
2,3,value1
2,8,value1
2,7,value1
```

desired output:

```
 id        type    value 
0   1  8,2,7,3,10  value1 
1   2       3,8,7  value1
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Can you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` `join`, but first convert `int` to `str`:

```
df = df.groupby('id')['type'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()
print (df)
   id        type
0   1  8,2,7,3,10
1   2       3,8,7
```

Comment: as a group when there are three columns (the third has the same value) - one group, to collect in the second list and a third leave? @jezrael

Comment: I am not sure if understand. Can you post new question with sample and desired output?

Comment: `value1` is same?

Comment: If yes, add column to `groupby` like `df = df.groupby(['id', 'value'])['type'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()`

Comment: what to do if there are different values? @jezrael

Comment: Then need aggregate by `agg` - e.g. `df.groupby('id').agg({'type': lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)), 'value': 'mean'}).reset_index()`

Comment: 'mean' -  Only for numeric values @jezrael

Comment: There are strings? Then it is possible use `df.groupby('id').agg({'type': lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)), 'value':  lambda x: ','.join(x)}).reset_index()` or `df.groupby('id').agg({'type': lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)), 'value':  'first'}).reset_index()`

Comment: the second option is suitable, thank you very much @jezrael

Comment: Super. Btw, in future better is create new question as edited old, becasue now my old answer not matched with new edited question ;)