# Combine rows by id making vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, rows

I'm having trouble to convert this:

```
Name(id)    Food 

John        Apple  
John        Beans
Anna        Apple
Anna        Banana
```

To this:

```
Name(id)    Food

John        c(Apple,Beans)
Anna        c(Apple,Banana)
```

I've found a solution to a similar problem with Python:
[Combine rows by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792089/combine-rows-by-id)
but couldn't do something similar on R.

Comment: Most probably you need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# import necessary package   
library(dplyr)

# reproduce the data
df <- data_frame(
  `Name(id)` = c("John", "John", "Anna", "Anna"),
  Food = c("Apple", "Beans", "Apple", "Banana")
)

# group by name and store food in a list
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(`Name(id)`) %>%
  summarise(Food = list(Food))

df2
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   `Name(id)` Food     
#   <chr>      <list>   
# 1 Anna       <chr [2]>
# 2 John       <chr [2]>
```